# Text RPG in python

Tags: python

**main.py**

```
import engine
engine.objects['key'] = "It's a key"
engine.main()
```

**engine.py**

```
# inventory = []

objects = {

}

def main():
    while True:
        choice = raw_input(">>: ")
        command, obj = choice.split()
        if command == 'examine':
            if obj in objects:
                print objects[obj]
            else:
                print 'joking right?'
        else:
            print 'joking right?'
```

When I type "examine" with no second word, the parameter, it gives me an error.

```
>>: asdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine.main()
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Programming\Game engine test\engine.py", line
 11, in main
    command, obj = choice.split()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I understand why, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

So we can eliminate the `raw_input()` from the problem, and boil this down to the following lines:

```
choice = 'examine'
result = choice.split()      # result == ['examine']
command, obj = result        # Boom.
```

The return value from `split()` is a list. When you only have one word (separated by spaces), like "examine", the list contains only one element.

Then, when you try to to unpack that list into `command` and `obj`, python says, "I can't do that. You're expecting two entries, but I only have one."

What you need to do is perform some intermediate checking:

```
args = choice.split()
if len(args) < 2:
    print 'Invalid command.'
    continue
command, obj = args
# ...
```

Comment: You'll need a little bit more - as it is, it will still *boom* - just after printing "Invalid command" :-)

Comment: @SeanVieira: Added a `continue`, thanks. I wanted to add more logic, but I decided to stick with fixing the OP's particular issue, as opposed to designing a text-based menu interface for the him.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped :D I can now finish my game with a new game engine :D

Comment: @user1564265, you're welcome. Remember, if an answer actually answers your question, you should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. (This and your other questions as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
args = choice.split()
command = args[0]
#Branch according to command here
#Most likely you will want to separate them into functions
if command == 'examine':
    if len(args) < 2:
       print 'Missing argument'
    else:
       obj = args[1]
       if obj in objects:
           print objects[obj]
       else:
           print 'joking right?'
else:
    print 'joking right?'
```

Also you might look at the [`cmd` module in the python standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html). You can basically create an object with `do_<MYCOMMANDNAME>` functions and it will issue a command prompt and looks at the first word as a `command` and look for a corresponding `do_command` function to execute with the rest of the arguments.